# How to develop Xamarin applications in Windows 7

Tags: windows, xamarin

Xamarin requires VS 2015 for its free version. Unfortunately, VS 2015 is not compatible with Windows 7. I've also tried to download Xamarin Studio but it seems it's no longer available for Windows.

Is there any way to install Xamarin in Windows 7?

Comment: Xamarin people say Xamarin Studio for Windows is [still available](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/188860/#Comment_188860) (even though they did not share the link).

Comment: @GSerg They really should have the download up there. VS support is very bad and needs a lot of fixing as everyone, including Xamarin, knows. Oh well :/

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2015 is compatible with Windows 7 Service Pack 1; you can check the system requirements [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx). Furthermore, Xamarin is also compatible with lower versions of Visual Studio 2015. You can check Xamarin system requirements [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/).

Comment: Visual Studio is compatible, [but the emulators are not](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63735/is-it-correct-that-theres-no-more-xs-for-windows-and-will-i-be-able-to-debug-with-vs).

Comment: You can use [Xamarin Android Player](https://www.xamarin.com/android-player) for Windows 7 instead of Visual Studio Android emulator.

Comment: You can use any emulator provided by the Android SDK/Google or use a third party emulator such as GenyMotion/Xamarin Android Player/etc.